# Regex to get literal match until next white space

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
/dev/sdu2 on /volumeUSB1/usbshare1-2 type fuseblk.ntfs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

What I am after is this `/volumeUSB1/usbshare1-2`. The second part of this path can always be something different, it won't always be `usbshare1-2`. However, the `/volumeUSB1/` will always be the same.

So my Idea is to have a regex that looks for `/volumeUSB1/` and everything up until the next white space.

I know this matches anything except white space:

```
([^\s]+)
```

However, I need to somehow get `/volumeUSB1/` in there, but I have a problem with it because I believe the `/` somehow have to be escaped and I don't know how.

Can you help me?

... Another way would be to `grep` or `awk` it somehow but I literally have zero experience in Bash, so I need to go the regex way and use PowerShells `Select-String`

Comment: `/volumeUSB1/[^\s/]*` or `/volumeUSB1/\S+` will match

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, that already works. thanks a lot!